# I cannot open Excel file

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office-2010

I have office 2010 installed and the file was working but suddenly when I try to open it
It gives me following error

> `Excel cannot open the file ... because the file format or the file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file.`

also I tried a program to repair it.

What can I do?

Comment: Is it an XLSX or XLS file? Did you save it as a different file format?

Comment: which program? upload the file (if u can).

Answer (score 1):

Change the file extension manually from `.xlsx` to `.xls` and try again.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem when going from Office 2003 to Office 2007. To fix this, edit your registry.

For Office 2007:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Excel\Security]
"AccessVBOM"=dword:00000001
"ExtensionHardening"=dword:00000000
```

For Office 2010:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Excel\Security]
"AccessVBOM"=dword:00000001
"ExtensionHardening"=dword:00000000
```

You can either manually make the above entries or copy and paste the text into Notepad and save it using the ".reg" extension. If you want to make a reg file make sure you leave a space between the first line, "Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00", and the next line, and place a space after the last line.

To save your reg file, go to File > Save As, browse to the place you want to save it and when you give it the name, enclose the name in quotes; e.g. "ExcelExtensionHardening.reg". Make sure to do all this in Notepad, not Word, WordPad, etc, as those programs will add things that make the reg file useless, and could possiblly hose your entire OS.

To apply your reg file, just double-click it.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open Excel, and click on the Microsoft Icon at the top left.
2. In the window at the bottom is "Excel Options". Click it.
3. Then select "Advanced" on the left side of the screen.
4. When the display comes up, you need to scroll almost to the bottom.
5. Under the blue "General" category, will be "Ignore other applications that use Dynamic Data Exchange " Make sure it is not checked.
6. Then Test it and see whether it works