# Excel document can not open

Tags: microsoft-excel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I cannot open Excel file](https://superuser.com/questions/219221/i-cannot-open-excel-file)

I formatted the hard drive  because I had trouble with trojan and saved my document on another hard drive but when I restored my document on the newly formated hard drive I can not open them and I get the following error message:

> Excel cannot open the file because the file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file

Comment: Formatting the hard drive seems out of place in this context, what was the reason? Are you saying you backed up data, formatted the drive, then restored the data? Was it a data disk or did you also re-install software? Based on answers to these questions, it could very well be that the data is corrupt.

Answer (score 1):

I have two possible solutions for you:

1. Download and install all the MS-Office updates for your version of MS-Office.  Sometimes I've found that an unpatched MS-Office can't open a document created by a patched MS-Office installation.
2. Download and install OpenOffice.org, and open the file with that.  Then you can either continue to use OpenOffice to work with your document, or save it in a different format that MS-Office can access again.

OpenOffice.org (free, open-source, and it won't interfere with MS-Office)
  http://www.openoffice.org/