# Excel document cannot open

Tags: microsoft-excel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Excel document can not open](https://superuser.com/questions/251804/excel-document-can-not-open)

I formatted the hard drive because I had trouble with trojan and saved my document on another hard drive but when I restored my document on the newly formated hard drive I can not open them and I get the following error message:

> Excel cannot open the file because the
>   file format or file extension is not
>   valid. Verify that the file has not
>   been corrupted and that the file
>   extension matches the format of the
>   file

Comment: Can you open the document on the other HDD?

Comment: No I can not. It displays the same message

Comment: Can you open the file when copied onto another PC with Excel installed?

Comment: duplicate of your [Excel document can not open](http://superuser.com/questions/251804/excel-document-can-not-open)

Answer (score 1):

Try opening the file in [OpenOffice](http://www.openoffice.org/), [LibreOffice](http://www.libreoffice.org/) or [Gnumeric](http://projects.gnome.org/gnumeric/)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that Excel has been re-installed properly? Windows on its own does not know how to open an xls file. Excel needs to be installed first.

Comment: Excel is well installed and I can see the documents

Answer (score 0):

The error message is probably right: the file is damaged to the point that Excel can't open it properly.  Excel has some built-in features to attempt to salvage some part of it: [Excel File Repair](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/repairing-corrupted-files-in-excel-HA001034656.aspx). If that doesn't work, you could attempt some of the various repair apps out there, but you may spend less time going to an old backup and building from there.