# Excel 2007 cannot open the file

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

I keep receiving the following:  Excel cannot open the file (name) because the file format or file extension is not valid.  Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file.  I had trouble yesterday and was told that I had to "take ownership" of the file, which I did.  Now I am getting this.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you make this Excel file, or get it from someone else?  Can you open other Excel files properly?  What version of Excel are you using?  What version was used to make the file you are trying to open?

Comment: possible duplicate of [I cannot open Excel file](http://superuser.com/questions/219221/i-cannot-open-excel-file)

Answer (score 1):

Try this fix, edit your Registry.

Go to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Excel\Security` and create these dwords if they are not already there, assigning the values listed:

```
"AccessVBOM"=dword:00000001
"ExtensionHardening"=dword:00000000
```

Answer (score 0):

The file might be corrupted. One way to check is to try and open it using an alternative app. The Open Source app called [LibreOffice](http://www.libreoffice.org/) can open Excel files and, like its counterpart, [Openoffice](http://www.openoffice.org/), has been known to be more tolerant of broken Excel/Word files than the equivalent Microsoft products.